# pandas pivot table using index data of dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to create a pivot table from a pandas dataframe
using dataframe.pivot()
and include not only dataframe columns but also the data within the dataframe index.
Couldn't find any docs that show how to do that.
Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please at least provide a minimal example to work with.

Answer (score 16):

Use `reset_index` to make the index a column:

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame({'y': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 'x': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3]}, index=np.arange(6)*10)

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
    x  y
0   1  0
10  2  1
20  2  2
30  3  3
40  1  4
50  3  4

In [47]: df.reset_index()
Out[47]: 
   index  x  y
0      0  1  0
1     10  2  1
2     20  2  2
3     30  3  3
4     40  1  4
5     50  3  4
```

So pivot uses the index as values:

```
In [48]: df.reset_index().pivot(index='y', columns='x')
Out[48]: 
   index        
x      1   2   3
y               
0      0 NaN NaN
1    NaN  10 NaN
2    NaN  20 NaN
3    NaN NaN  30
4     40 NaN  50
```